# Adding a user-agent doesn't help in solving 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError'

Tags: python-requests, python-3.7

I am trying to download a movie automatically from the following website;

**http://renrencili8.org/**

Below are my codes:

```
import requests,bs4,pyperclip,webbrowser
from urllib.request import quote

movie='复仇者联盟'
#movie name

url='http://renrencili8.org/query/'+quote(movie)+'/1-0-0/'
#url of the search page of the move

headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}
#add a header in response to the anti-crawler scheme

res=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
#download the seach page of the movie

bssearch=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
#parse the page

search_link=bssearch.select('.item dt sup a')
# select the link by the tags of the page

print(search_link)
# I assumed a dict would be printed, showing the link
```

but the result turns out to be:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054,

I have tried to research the solution, most of which recommend that this is because the anti-crawler scheme, and a user-agent shall be added.

I have already added the headers in my code, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Why is the error

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054,

still there ?

even if I have already add the user-agent in the code below:

```
headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}
#add a header in response to the anti-crawler scheme

res=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
#download the seach page of the movie
```

And how can I solve it?

Comment: @halfer thanks for your advice. I have edited my questions. is it specific to you now?

Comment: I would guess that "Connection aborted" means the other party is terminating your connection, so you cannot scrape. Are you running this code on your local machine, or on a remote scraping server? Your IP address could have been blacklisted. Could you perhaps try running it from another IP address?

Comment: I just tried your code and received a 200 response from the server.  I have a different IP address.  So, as halfer suggested, maybe your IP has been blacklisted.

Comment: Thanks for your help@halfer, I have tried my codes on a different laptop, but it is still not working.

Comment: @user212514, thanks for your information. it's good to know that my codes works on your computer.